# TextView StringIndexOutOfBoundsException and IndexOutOfBoundsException crashes in processToSupportEmoji

Tags: android, textview

I've received a small number of Crittercism crash reports with stack traces similar to the stack traces below.  The crashes do not originate in my code.

This forum post suggests it may be due to bugs in custom OEM implementations of the TextView:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/_53F4WBM8-I

Can anybody confirm if this is the case?  Even though very few users are affected, I'd be interested to know if there is a fix/workaround?

So far my crash reports show these devices are affected:

- ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 903 on OS 2.3.6
- ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 918D on OS 2.3.6
- ALCATEL ONE TOUCH 991D on OS 2.3.6
- Parrot on OS 2.3.5
- A102S_MULA on OS 2.3.4
- T9199+ on OS 2.3.5
- Trident A7 on OS 2.3.6

Stack trace for the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
at  java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:1059)
at  android.text.SpannableStringInternal.getChars(SpannableStringInternal.java:102)
at  android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:101)
at  android.text.Layout.processToSupportEmoji(Layout.java:3752)
at  android.text.Layout.supportTabandEmoji(Layout.java:3790)
at  android.text.Layout.measureText2(Layout.java:3148)
at  android.text.Layout.getDesiredWidth2(Layout.java:183)
at  android.text.Layout.getDesiredWidth2(Layout.java:161)
at  android.widget.TextView.onMeasure2(TextView.java:5950)
at  android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:6163)
at  android.view.View.measure(View.java:8396)
at  android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:612)
at  android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:396)
at  android.view.View.measure(View.java:8396)
at  android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1862)
at  android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1789)
at  android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:705)
at  android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:762)
at  android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
at  android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1299)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1520)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:943)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1285)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1161)
at  android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1078)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:369)
at  android.view.View.layout(View.java:7225)
at  android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1189)
at  android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1914)
at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at  android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3833)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: getChars (6 ... 8) ends beyond length 7
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1104)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1008)
at  android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:101)
at  android.text.Layout.processToSupportEmoji(Layout.java:3752)
at  android.text.Layout.supportTabandEmoji(Layout.java:3790)
at  android.text.StaticLayout.generate2(StaticLayout.java:722)
at  android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:404)
at  android.text.DynamicLayout.access$000(DynamicLayout.java:70)
at  android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:592)
at  android.text.DynamicLayout$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(DynamicLayout.java:604)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1050)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:470)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:387)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replaceInternal(SpannableStringBuilder.java:593)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:542)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:527)
at  android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:67)
at  android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:701)
at  android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.commitText(BaseInputConnection.java:227)
at  com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.commitText(EditableInputConnection.java:153)
at  com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:304)
at  com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:106)
at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
at  android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3833)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at  dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Happens on some specific devices. Happens when smiles are displayed in EditText/TextView.

Comment: My workaround is to replace smiles with "xxx" and insert ImageSpan to display a smile. Fixes the crash but I can only apply it to TextView not to EditText. This fix will not fit all, it's just for my specific case.